# Beginner guitar learning I,IV & V

Tags: electric-guitar

I'm learning Green Onions. I have the base part down, simple Fm, Bb, Cm. but I can't figure out the chords, I, IV,V to play along with that. I have recorded the base part on a looper and want to play a rhythm over it. I'm told to use 1st inversions. But I'm lost.

Comment: So, F, Bb, C are intended bass melody, and you want to decide chords on it? But if you have made up your mind that they are Fm, Bb, Cm, then isn't it f minor? Then what is the question? I don't get it, sorry....

Comment: I added a comment below Tim's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's in a pretty standard 12 bar format, originally in Fm. So, 1st 4 bars, F, Ab, Bb. Next 2 Bb(maj) Db,Eb, 2 as beginning, then - C, Eb, F; Bb,Db,Eb; last 2 as beginning.

The only questionable bit for me is bar 9, where I've heard C *or* Cm. However it's a blues, so could be either - I play whatever sounds better on the night...

Bass pattern for 8 of the bars is F F Ab Bb C. Other bars follow on appropriate roots.It appears to be in a Dorian mode.

Comment: Realize I'm new with this, but what I think I'm wanting to do is play the 12 bar part through a looper and play rhythm chords on top of it? If that makes sense. Since I'm by myself but want to hear more than the bass. My teacher has me trying to use inversions over it, but I'm just confused..

Comment: OP, can you write down a instance you are dissatisfied with? This is too abstract.

Comment: It's 12 bar blues as Tim pointed out. Please see his answer above. I have recorded the 12 bar bass in Fm, using the 12 bar format. Now I want to play a complimentary rhythm on top of that. So it sounds like two guitars. Listen to an original recording of Steve Cropper playing along with Booker T & The MG's. I hope I'm doing better st explaining.

Answer (score 0):

It follows a standard blues progression of I IV I V IV I, but it includes other chords, playing the 3rd and 4th chords above the primary chords. The riff plays F5 (or Fm) for the I chord, and riffs Ab Bb, so F5 F5 Ab Bb, then when it changes to the IV chord Bb Bb Db Eb (Db is the third above Bb and Eb is the forth).  On the V chord it goes C Eb F.

Your bass notes should be F Ab Bb C.

Comment: Standard blues progression is mostly 12 bars long - as is Green Onions.